# Limit connection per domain source

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, virtualhost, connection

I would like to limit my http request for only one virtualhost on apache, is it possible to do this via iptables for only one virtualhost ?
I prefer to do not use apache if it's possible for better performance.
If not how I can limit requests for only one virtualhost on apache 2.2 ?

Comment: On your question "How do I prevent Apache from answering requests for domains I don't host?" I don't see any answer for my issue, I just want to limit one virtualhost, I don't want to block all my traffic from it.

Comment: Assuming the "limit" in this question means "rate limit", then this is not a duplicate of that question. You can rate limit packets with iptables, getting a predictable bandwidth usage is a bit more tricky. The iptables rules can only be applied per IP address. If you are using name based vhosts on a single IP address, then you cannot do it at the packet layer, and iptables won't be the right tool.